# Cassandra initial queries slows with concurrency

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, cassandra, datastax

I'm doing 1000 inserts of about 36kb of data into a four node Cassandra cluster.  The client is written in C# using the latest DataStax driver.

I'm spinning up threads (TPL tasks) to do this, sharing the C* session.  Before I start timing the inserts, I do one blocking read (from the same keyspace as the inserts, on an empty table) per thread, trying to wake up/warm up pools/etc.  The threadpool has ~1000 normal and io threads available at the start of the process.

The main problem I have is this wakeup period takes quite some time as the thread count increases.  The session is created outside of these timings - this is just the time to execute one select query per thread.

```
Threads  Time(s)
1        0
2        0
4        0
8        1
16       5
32       17
64       52
128      112
```

Once the thread/connection pool/whatever has woken up, the inserts are executed quickly.  Why do the first queries take so long, though?  Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: This could _possibly_ be related to your underlying hardware not your code or the DB. If you operations are loading into the disc buffer cache (i.e. like pre-warming the cache) then that might be the reason. Perhaps you could share you hardware configuration details of your nodes and provide some more details in this area? This article might also be useful for background reading: http://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/04/20/buffer-cache-makes-slow-disks-seem-fast-till-you-need-them/